# How to extract class names from html tag

Tags: html, xpath, xidel

I am trying extract 2nd class name from `<span>` tag.

Due xidel documentation is really poor. I can't understand how to
use function `filter()` or `contains()` 
and match `<span>` tag with
class name "userstatus" and extract 2nd class name.

I have this at the moment but I can't tell to XIDEL tool match span tag with class when one parameter contain word userstatus.

```
xidel -e http://intranet.website.com '//li[@class='status']/span[@class==match("userstatus").....
```

Thank you for any suggestions

```
<li class="status">
  <span class="userstatus offline strongfont2">
    blaa bllaa foo text
  </span>
</li>

<li class="status">
  <span class="userstatus online italicfont1">
    blaa bllaa foo text
  </span>
</li>`
```

I need extract **class parameters** of `<span>` tag.
I don't need text or HTML content of `<span>` tag.

Result look like this:

class="**userstatus offline strongfont2**"

class="**userstatus online italicfont1**"

Comment: *I have this at the moment but its not good syntax* - What does this mean?

Comment: @obi2016 If you still wonder why you didn't get any output with the `xidel` binary, it's because the `-e` option is in the wrong place. --> `xidel <url> -e '<extraction query>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find `<span>` elements where the `class` attribute value contains `"userstatus"` and then return the `class`, you can use the following XPath 1.0 expression :

```
//li[@class='status']/span[contains(@class, 'userstatus')]/@class
```

Since Xidel seems to support XPath 2.0, you can use the following expression to extract only the second CSS class from the above `<span>` elements :

```
for $span in //li[@class='status']/span[contains(@class, 'userstatus')] 
return tokenize($span, ' ')[2]
```

I've never used Xidel before, but the above XPath seems to work when tested in  [Xidel online tester](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi). You can also see demo of the above XPath in [xpathtester.com](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/e84a003f93eb6af189f01d16a8298f34)

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I want to extract. But xidel is not printing result. It's working fine in testing tool but not with XIDEL binary no output... :( But we are close to solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery.hasClass() for determining whether the HTML element has a particular class associated or not - [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) [Example](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-has-a-particular-class/)

Comment: sorry i am writting shell script. I need explain how to use XIDEL features filter(....) and contains[.....] extracted data will be processes and validated in shell-script later. I am looking for pure XIDEL solution. It;s possible but I dont know how to write query :(

Comment: Simplier how to extract this line   <span class="userstatus online italicfont1"> when is parent <li class="status">. But class  parameters may dynamic . only 3 words are always there  **"userstatus" online** or **offline**. That's all.